# What's the difference between `twoFingerTap()` and `tap(withNumberOfTaps:1 numberOfTouches:2)` when running it on Fastlane?

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane, xcuitest

I have been working with UI test on iOS, and using XCUITest on swift. In one test I need to tap with two fingers on the screen at the same time. I used [`twoFingerTap()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1618675-twofingertap) . The test passes when I run it from Xcode. But running by command line with fastlane it fails. Then, a coworker suggested to change it to [`tap(withNumberOfTaps:1 numberOfTouches:2)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1618671-tap), and it works when running on both ways. I have no idea why this different behavior from actions that should be doing the same thing. Somebody knows?

First attempt:

> appUnderTest.twoFingerTap()

Second attempt:

> appUnderTest.tap(withNumberOfTaps: 1, numberOfTouches: 2)

Fastlane Command:

> bundle exec fastlane scan --scheme "MyApp" --device "iPhone 13" --force_quit_simulator --prelaunch_simulator --reset_simulator

Answer (score 1):

`twoFingerTap()` does not tap twice, it simulates tapping with two fingers at the same time, I don't really understand how it works locally. To achieve what you want you need to use `doubleTap()`. Unless you meant that you actually want to do two-finger tap, in this case your question is not stated properly.

Comment: hello! I have edited my question. I meant tapping with two fingers at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

These two methods should be equivalent (either in Xcode, or when running the simulator via the command line as Fastlane does). I'd suggest filing a bug with Apple.